# How many members can be added to a group in AD?

Tags: windows, active-directory, groups

How many members can be added to a Security group in AD ? Nesting or members .The total count that a group can hold the AD users.

Comment: Your google-foo needs work - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/active-directory-maximum-limits-scalability(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score -1):

From [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/active-directory-maximum-limits-scalability(v=ws.10).aspx):

> Production environments have been reported to exceed 4 million
>   members, and Microsoft scalability testing reached 500 million members

Comment: Please don't just copy/paste content from external sources.